# How to correct scaling / font in dialogs of application settings

Tags: windows-10, fonts, scaling, exact-audio-copy

I recently had some kind of corruption during Windows 10 updates and my computer wouldn't start. I was able to reinstall Windows 10 successfully, and am in the process of re-installing some programs that got removed in the process.

One anomaly I've noticed in one program - Exact Audio Copy - is that when I open any settings dialogs, the font is wrong. It means that I can't see/access some of the settings - the window is not resizable. Here's a screenshot:
[image: EAC screenshot]

Exact Audio Copy (EAC) is a freeware program. This build (1.3) was released on 2016-09-04. Just to confirm it's not something specific to this version, I stepped back to 1.2 and 1.1, but the issue remains. Before re-installing Windows, I had been using EAC 1.1 and I didn't have this problem.

I'm not sure if the problem is related to a missing font since I re-installed Windows, or if it is something to do with Windows' "Scale and layout" setting - I have this set to 125% on my computer, and I've experimented with settings 100% and 150%, but the problem is the same.

One other thing I tried was to go into Properties of EAC.exe and (under the Compatibility tab) change the "high DPI settings", where I checked "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: Application". This also had no effect.

How can I restore the correct display of text in these settings dialogs?

Comment: Scaling is almost always the cause of issues like this. Did you try setting it to 100% and logging off and back on to the computer then checking your program?

Comment: In PC Settings > System > Display > Advanced scaling settings, try to set "Let Windows try to ﬁx apps so they're not blurry".

Comment: Also in the Properties of the EAC executable, Compatibility tab, under settings, try the other settings of “Override high DPI scaling behavior”, starting with "System (Enhanced)".

Comment: @Appleoddity I tried it again - set to 100% and rebooted. The issue didn't change.

Comment: @harrymc I already have the setting enabled to "Let Windows try to ﬁx apps so they're not blurry". I tried the suggestions in your second comment - actually, "System (Enhanced)" seemed to make the situation even worse - I could see even less text. The "System" setting didn't seem to change anything compared to my screenshot.

Comment: Strange - "System (Enhanced)" solved my own scaling problems. What are your display adapter and driver?

Comment: Could be a corrupt font then. Do you have another windows 10 installation you can copy the c:\windows\fonts folder from?

Comment: @harrymc My laptop uses a NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M. I just updated the driver from Nvidia today - driver version 24.21.13.9793 from 2018-05-22

Comment: @Appleoddity hmmm no. Not for several weeks or months anyway

Comment: Try the information at this link: https://www.rizonesoft.com/restore-default-fonts-in-windows-10/